# Race, Class, Level Limitation List

Tags: adnd-1e

Is there a definitive list for race, class, and level limitations in regards to PCs and NPCs.  I'm aware of the table (*Character Race Table II.: Class Level Limitations*) in the PHB.  However, is it possible for an NPC Dwarf Cleric to multi-class?

I am only concerned with RAW (rules-as-written).

At this time I am not considering *Unearthed Arcana*, but will consider anything printed in *Dragon Magazine* prior to the release of UA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and it's alluded to in the Monster Manual.  If you dig deep enough, a theoretical high of 11th for a Dwarven cleric, based on a City Encounter, might be the cap, but the standard cap of 8th level from Table II in the PHB is more supportable.

**Rules-as-Written**

Outside of *Unearthed Arcana*, there's not another table or list like the one you mention.

***In the Monster Manual***, p. 35, under the entry for Dwarf:

> If 200 or more are encountered there will be a **fighter/cleric of 3rd
>   to 6th level fighting ability and *4th to 7th level clerical* ability in
>   addition to the others.**  If 320 or more dwarves are encountered there
>   will be the following additional dwarves with the group: an 8th level
>   fighter, a 7th level fighter, **a *6th level fighter/7th level cleric***,
>   and ***two 4th level fighter/clerics*.**  If encountered in their lair (home)
>   there will be in addition from 2-12 fighters of from 2nd to 5th level,
>   from ***2-8 fighter/clerics of*** from 2nd to 4th level (each category), and
>   females and young equal to 50% and 25% respectively of the number of
>   adult males.

You will find similar entries to various non-human races in the Monster Manual for gnomes, orcs, goblins, etcetera.  The above gives solid RAW support for the 6/7 NPC dwarf Fighter/Cleric.

Consider the max level for a dwarf fighter(9) and consider multi-class.

Multi Class: Let's look at the numbers of XP.
Cleric:  level 8  110001 -225,000
Fighter: level 8  125,001-250,000
Fighter: level 9  250,001-500,000

8/8 looks like a solid max for a Dwarf Fighter/Cleric NPC.

**Rules Fun**

Is there a higher level dwarf cleric possible in the rules?  If you just roll dice on the City Encounters table, you could argue that the rules support a cap at 11th level.

DMG, on page 191, City Encounters Matrix.  There is:
a chance for a cleric encounter with
a chance for it to be a demi-human (31-00 human, 01 -30 demi human)
a chance for it to be a dwarf. (if the percentile roll came up 01-08)
The level of the cleric is also chosen by a die roll.

> Cleric encounters will be with a cleric 6th to 11th.  Level (d6 + 5).
>   There will be 0-5 lesser clerics (d4for level) with the major
>   character. Alignment can be rolled for or dictated by area or race.
>   Encountered clerics will typically try to convert the party, ask for
>   contributions, or try to dupe the party becoming sacrificial victims.

With the dice as your guide, you *could* encounter an 11th level Dwarf Cleric in a city, although the hard cap of (8) in the PHB (aimed at NPC clerics) is a stricter RAW reading.

RAW it from the Monster Manual? Cap it a F/C 6/7.

The simplest?  **Max NPC cleric levels at (8) per Table II of the PHB**  (*Numbers in Parentheses () indicate that this class exists only as non-player characters in the race in question*.  PHB. p. 14).  That gives you a supportable Dwarven 8/8 Fighter/Cleric.

---

**It's 1e, and you're the DM**

Since you're the DM, you can choose to make a multi-class dwarf *something*/cleric.  As long as this character remains an NPC, you won't run into any issues.  Some notes in the 1e DMG and *guidelines versus rules* which means that these are also *rules as written* for DM's ... :

> (From the Preface)
>   ADVANCED D&D is more than a framework around which individual DMs construct their respective milieu ... **When you build your campaign you will tailor it to suit your personal tastes.**
>
> page 9
>      The final word, then, **is the game**. Read how and why the system is as it is, follow the parameters, and then cut portions as needed to maintain excitement.

If you wanted to make a "Thief/Cleric" you could, but I didn't find any reference to one.  Given that the DMG for 1e has a variety of entries from E. Gary Gygax *on the latitude you as a DM have for customizing your world*, it's technically an option.

As to an "assassin/cleric" DMG page 18 yields RAW as "No!"

> MULTI-CLASSED ASSASSIN
>    Race  /  dwarf  / *no other class permitted*

---

Dragon article in #129 addressed Dwarf Clerics, but that is 1988, after the 1985 UA printing.

Comment: +1 for _Monster Manual_.  At the time of writing the question, I didn't have that book handy.  I should have stated RAW, and have edited my question to include that.  I didn't consider the **follower** restrictions to be a hard and fast rule, however if there is nothing to contradict it, then I must consider it.